# Is there a tool like XMing to manage X11 forwarded applications?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

Sorry the title is not quite clear.

With X11 forwarding, I could run application on the remote server but see it on the local client. Normally I do this by:

```
local$ ssh -X remote_server  
remote$ xclock
```

Is there a tool like XMing that could manage all these steps?

I mean I do not have to open a remote login explicitly. The tool will open it if necessary.

And I do not have to run the application by type its command. Just like I run other applications, for example from a menu.

Answer (score 0):

NOT that I know of.

That's basically the way SSH X11 Forwarding works.

You'll have to connect to the SSH Server by specifying `-X` or `-Y`, of course sshd should allow `X11Forwarding`.

To run X client applications like Firefox, chrome, you'll have to execute the application in CLI and probably run it in background and redirect the stdout and stderr to the black hole `>/dev/null 2>&1 &`.

There are some misunderstandings in your statement.

xclock is actually a X client, it is executed on the remote SSH Server but is displayed on the X Server where ssh client resides (your Ubuntu Desktop or Xming X Server for Windows).